# Consulta a 3 tablas y que el resultado sea por id el mayor en `Sql server`

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo 3 tablas y tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
select S.ID, C.IDSENSOR, C.ID, CF.IDCANAL, MAX(CF.ENTRY_ID) as entry, cf.estado
  from Sensor as S
    join  Canal as C on S.Id = C.IdSensor
    join  CanalFeed as CF on C.Id = CF.IdCanal
where S.Id = 1 
GROUP BY S.ID,C.IDSENSOR,C.ID,CF.IDCANAL, cf.estado
order by CF.IDCANAL
```

Me arroja el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como cambiaría esa consulta para que traiga por cada id canal el mayor (ENTRY_ID). Marco en rojo como solo quiero que me traiga la consulta.

**Edicion**

Como haría para que me traiga solo los marcados en rojos ya que seria por cada id canal me traiga el mayor por ENTRY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es una ordenación en base a este Entry_Id y obtener su posición según sea de mayor a menor. Luego simplemente te bastaría con quedarte con los números 1 (los mayores)

```
select * from 
(
select S.ID, C.IDSENSOR, C.ID CanalId, CF.IDCANAL, MAX(CF.ENTRY_ID) as entry, cf.estado,
DENSE_RANK() over (partition by CF.IDCANAL order by MAX(CF.ENTRY_ID) desc) rnk
  from Sensor as S
    join  Canal as C on S.Id = C.IdSensor
    join  CanalFeed as CF on C.Id = CF.IdCanal
where S.Id = 1 
GROUP BY S.ID,C.IDSENSOR,C.ID,CF.IDCANAL, cf.estado
) CF
where rnk = 1
order by CF.IDCANAL
```

Con esto debería de salirte como quieres

Answer (score 2):

debes usar `MAX(CAMPO)` para entry_id y `agrupar` por los otros campos
prueba de la siguiente manera

```
select  S.ID, C.IDSENSOR, C.ID, CF.IDCANAL, MAX(CF.ENTRY_ID)
from Sensor as S
    join  Canal as C on S.Id = C.IdSensor
    join  CanalFeed as CF on C.Id = CF.IdCanal
where S.Id = 1 AND cf.estado = '@cheerlights green'
GROUP BY S.ID,C.IDSENSOR,C.ID,CF.IDCANAL
order by CF.IDCANAL
```

Comment: Disculpa tuve que cambiar la consulta porque era lo que realmente necesitaba. @MauroPetrini

Comment: agregas en la clausula where esto: and cf.estado = '@cheerlights green', ahi edite. de igual manera si son distintas consultas, crea otra pregunta.

Comment: quiero obtener el estado por maximo entry id, asi entry id tenga '@cheerlights red' debo tomar ese. @MauroPetrini. Si entry id fuera 6 y el estado y su estaod es '@cheerlights red' debo tomar este estado.

Comment: osea tu consulta deberia devolver un unico resultado? solo validar el entry id maximo. y el id canal no afecta?

Comment: Debería en el ejemplo darme 3 resultado por cada id canal que me devuelva el max de entry @MauroPetrini